# Javascript injected into a PDF, communicating with a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

My questions concern Javascript injected in a pdf.

1. From what I have seen there doesn't really seem to be an alternative for Adobe Professional for injecting js into a pdf. Am I wrong about that?
2. Is there a way for a pdf to communicate with a website using javascript (or any other means for that matter) in order to update data in the pdf on-the-fly?

Comment: Doesn't this all kind of miss the point of a PDF? You might as well just build this as a web page.

Comment: In a way i guess it does and I guess what I am trying to build is a real niche product. It's supposed to be a pdf that will automatically update to the latest version if you happen to be connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are multiple libraries out there that allow you to edit PDF files from within your app (and not require Acrobat). Just pick one for your language/framework. For .NET I would recommend PDF4NET from O2 Solutions.
2. Yes and no. As far as I know net APIs only work when PDF is open inside browser plugin and not available if you open it in Acrobat.